# complex integral: $\int_C \frac{e^z+\sin{z}}{z}dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

> Evaluate:
>   $$\int_C \frac{e^z+\sin{z}}{z}dz$$
>   where, $C$ is the circle $|z|=5$ traversed once in the counterclockwise direction.

I can't find an anti-derivative to this function, and I am not sure one exists.  I was thinking about using several theorems but each come up short.  For instance, I cannot use the **Closed Curve Theorem** since the function in the integrand is not entire (at least I don't think it is).

Any hints (to help get me started)?

Comment: For example, you could use [Cauchy's integral formula](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_integral_formula)

Comment: But the function is not entire, so how can I use Cauchy's Integral Formula?

Comment: The numerator is entire, and that's all you need for the formula.  Don't confuse this with Cauchy's integral theorem, which is specifically about the integral of entire functions.

Comment: Ah!  Thank you for that last comment.  I get it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(z) = e^z + \sin z$, then by [Cauchy's Integral Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CauchyIntegralFormula.html) we have

$$2\pi i f(0) = \int_C \frac{e^z + \sin z }{z - 0} dz \implies \int_C \frac{e^z + \sin z }{z - 0} dz = \color{#f03}{ 2\pi i} $$